# Angular 2 routing from outside of angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have an angular2 app with two routes. Something like this:

```
{path: 'foo/A', component: FooAComponent}
{path: 'foo/B', component: FooBComponent}
```

How can I open the two components with JavaScript from outside of my angular app?

Thanks in regard!

Comment: I don't understand what "open two components with JavaScript from outside" could mean.

Comment: Inside of angular I could create a-tags like this: `<a routerLink="/foo/A">fooA</a>`. Then I can click in the browser on this a-tag and then the `FooAComponent` shows up. I want to open this route not via clicking on the link in the browser. I want to open the route with not-angula-javascript, like `window.location.href = "foo/A";`. But this also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just copy the url from the browsers url bar after you clicked `<a routerLink="/foo/A">fooA</a>`

Comment: This doesn't work, because then my app won't start again.

Comment: I have still absolutely no idea what this question is about. Perhaps someone else.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I asked not very clearly :D

Comment: `window.location.href='/user'` this way it's working for me.

Comment: I have the same problem ... i have a already build angular application. This app is already running ... now i want to navigate execution some vanilla js inside the browser document. Changing `window.location` forces a reload of the page ...